# 13.04 64 bit / Kernel panic after updating Ralink rt5390 wifi driver

Tags: lubuntu

I'm running Lubuntu 13.04 64 bit. Today I installed the official Linux driver and related patch for my notebooks Ralink rt5390 wifi by following these step outlined on the thread at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138302 (post #4)

So my wifi is full strength now which is good, but whenever I run Spotify, and in some circumstances when using Chromium I get a kernel panic and the terminal spits out a bunch of text which means nothing to me. I have checked the logs in /var/log, including kern.log but no mention is made of the crash.rm

I have seen some other distros have tools for capturing this information

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Its a kernel regression, the patch to fix the issue is here

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2705091/